# Получение данных из формы js/php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, form

У меня есть форма , которая обрабатывается с помощью PHP кода. Суть её в том, что человек заполняет поля, нажимает "создать!" и в таблице с лобби создаётся строка с лобби, которое создал этот человек. Строка создаётся следующим jQuery кодом:

```js
$(".submit").click(function(event) {
  $("#lobbies-list").find("tbody")
    .append($("<tr>")
      .append($("
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>' .$_SESSION['USER_NAME'].' </td>
                  <td>**Тут должен выводится статус (status)**</td>
                  <td>1\2</td>
                  <td>**а тут ставка** (bet)</td>
                  <td><span>играть!</span></td>")

      )
    );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="/play" class="animation-form">
  <input type="text" id="status" name="status" maxlength="23" pattern="{0,23}" placeholder="Статус">
  <input type="text" id="bet" name="bet" pattern="[\d+(\.\d{2})?]{1,10}" placeholder="Ставка [формата 9.99]" required>
  <input type="submit" name="enter" value="создать!" class="submit">
</form>
```

Проблема в том, что переменная `' .$_SESSION['USER_NAME'].'` корректно отображается в новосозданой строке, а вот тот же `$_POST['status']`, если его вставить в скрипт - не работает. Как сделать так, чтобы в создаваемой строке таблицы, отображались данные, которые ввёл пользователь в форму?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Нельзя переносить строку JS на несколько строк документа, откуда у вас берётся `$_SESSION` в JS коде вообще не понятно (возможно это часть переменной PHP), убрал что бы работал пример.
Добавил блок куда вставлять и зачем у вас отправлялась форма тоже не понятно, если вы хотите просто вывести.

```js
$(".submit").click(function() {
  $("#lobbies-list").find("tbody").append(
    $("<tr>").append(
      $("<td>1</td> <td>имя</td> <td>" + $('.animation-form #status').val() + "</td> <td>1\2</td> <td>" + $('.animation-form #bet').val() + "</td> <td><span>играть!</span></td>")
      //строка в одну строчку
    )
  );
  return false; //что бы форма не отправилась
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="#" class="animation-form">
  <input type="text" id="status" name="status" maxlength="23" pattern="{0,23}" placeholder="Статус">
  <input type="text" id="bet" name="bet" pattern="[\d+(\.\d{2})?]{1,10}" placeholder="Ставка [формата 9.99]" required="">
  <input type="submit" name="enter" value="создать!" class="submit">
</form>
<!-- блок куда вставлять инофрмацию -->
<div id="lobbies-list">
  <table>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Вы - самый лучший человек на земле, как минимум на сегодняшний вечер !
А форма отправляет данные в базу )

Comment: @BimBam тут принято благодарять, отмечая ответ полезным и правильным (стрелка вверх и галочка ниже)